# Prestashop get ajax response showing as null

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop I am doing a small module. In that module in smarty I have a form. I want to submit those values using ajax. So for that I have made my ajax as $.post like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.module-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      msg = '';
    $form = $(this);
      $.post(
        baseDir + "modules/mymodule/mymodule.php",
        { name: 'myname', action: 'form_subscribe' }, 
        function(data) {
          var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(response);
        }
      );
  return false;
  });
});
```

In the module file (mymodule.php) I have my code like this

```
class MyModule extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
    -----
    ----
    --
    }

    function form_subscribe() {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      echo json_encode($name);
      exit;
    }
}
```

But when I am doing submit the form it is showing the response as null. Can someone tell me how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: You're just making a request to a class, it doesn't answer anything, that's why response is null

Comment: So can you tell me how to get the values inside the class and use that? Any better method?

Comment: your ajax request must have a link to a PHP script where you can use your MyModule functions

Comment: Yes that I want to know. Any reference code or any example?

Comment: Replace `modules/mymodule/mymodule.php` by `test.php` and in this script make `<?php echo json_encode("test");` You should get an answer from your ajax request. When it works, modify test.php by including your MyModule class

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a class or a method directly like you are trying to do.
To perform your action you have to first instantiate the Class and then call the function.
Particularly in a prestashop environment, follow this step:
Create another php page inside your module folder, lets call the page mymodule_ajax.php. 
Then inside of it retrieve the configuration, the initialization of the prestashop context and then instantiate the module and perform the call management.

mymodule_ajax.php:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__). '/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__). '/../../init.php');

/* will include module file */
include(dirname(__FILE__). '/mymodule.php');

/* will instantiate the class MyModule so that you can access the method */
$my_mod = new MyModule;

/* using Prestashop Tools Class we ensure that the call is made from the form with action "form_subscribe */    
if(Tools::isSubmit('action') && Tools::getValue('action') == 'form_subscribe')
            $my_mod->form_subscribe(); //call the method
```

Then change your ajax code to point that url so:

```
  $.post(
    baseDir + "modules/mymodule/mymodule_ajax.php", //new url
    { name: 'myname', action: 'form_subscribe' }
```

You should now retrieve the json value in your console.log.